# Elliptic PDE or index theory tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I ask [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163800/elliptic-and-fredholm-partial-differential-operators) in MO. then a user suggested me to ask it at MSE. But I could not find Elliptic PDE tag or index theory tag. Is it a good idea to suggest to MSE to produce such tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elliptic equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elliptic-equations) already exists.

I am slightly skeptical about "index theory": this phrase  appears in [5 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22index+theory%22+is%3Aq), and they are on different topics. While I do not strongly object to the tag, my expectation is that in a year's time we would find it filled mostly with questions about changing the index from $k$ to $k+1$ in some sum.

Comment: thank you I added Elliptic equation to my question. Hoever there is no a tag "diff operators" which is suitable to my question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-operators

Comment: I really thank you very much for your help.